# How to attach a file to a vcalendar event?

Tags: java, attachment, vcalendar

I am trying to attach a file to a calendar event invite generated using Java. I want to attach a blob object as an attachment,but I unable to attach even a basic file.

I tried using the ATTACH tag in the calendar event template as follows:
"ATTACH;FMTTYPE=image/jpeg:http://farm1.static.flickr.com/183/411545406_c73ca4e613_t.jpg"

But it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Tanvi